# ¿Cómo puedo solucionar este problema al intentar modificar un header?

Tags: php, html

Este es mi código:

**login.php**

```php
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['LoggedIn'])) {header('Location: personajes'); exit();}?>
//formulario en html
<?php
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    $u=$_POST['usuarioingresado'];
    if(!empty($u))
    {   
        $c=$_POST['contraingresada'];
        if(!empty($c))
        {
        include 'lib/con-pdo.php';
        $ce=strtoupper(hash('whirlpool', $c));
        $usql=("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sv_nicks WHERE Nick = :u or Email = :u and Contra = :ce");
        $stmt1=$db->prepare($usql);
        $stmt1->execute(array(":u" => $u, ":ce" => $ce));
            if($stmt1->fetchColumn()==1)
            {
                $_SESSION['LoggedIn']=$u;header('Location: personajes/index.php');
            }else{echo "<script>document.getElementById('error').innerHTML='Los datos de inicio de sesión son incorrectos.'</script>";}
        }else{echo "<script>document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = 'Debes ingresar una contraseña.'</script>";}
    }else{echo "<script>document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = 'Debes ingresar un usuario o e-mail.'</script>";}
}
require_once 'views.php';
?>
```

Y el error que no me deja modificar el header es este:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\pcu\index.php:2) in C:\xampp\htdocs\pcu\index.php on line 18

Comment: Intentas redireccionar cuando pase las validaciones?

Comment: Exactamente, necesito que los mande a la main.php, por así decirlo...